# Where in Tokyo can I sell/give-away US electronics (specifically home appliances)?

Tags: japan

I lived for a short time in the US about 3 years ago and had some home appliances (a electric wok, electric kettle, two electric blenders) bought brand new. But had to move back to India immediately so I didn't get a chance to use these appliances. I figured I'd go back so I brought them with me to India.

I couldn't use these appliances in India because our electricity is 220v-240v. I don't see myself or anyone I know going to US anytime soon. I tried selling it online in a group where students who were aspiring to go to US for studies but nobody got back to me. I think it's generally a hassle for them to carry stuff from here when they can buy it easily over there.

I know that in Japan, US electrical appliances work without much trouble. I will be visiting Tokyo in August. Is there any place in Tokyo where I can go and sell off these US appliances? Even giving away for a good cause would do. These appliances are brand new (with exception of blenders which I've used a couple of times) and have never been used.

Comment: You should add the value of the appliances. Customs fees might be an issue, especially if they are new in original packaging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greg Lane's [Tokyo Cheapo](https://tokyocheapo.com/) article in 2016, [5 Ways to Recycle or Dispose of Stuff](https://tokyocheapo.com/living/household/recycling-and-disposing-of-stuff-cheaply-in-japan/), has a number of suggestions.

> **Facebook Groups**
>   There are a number of groups on Facebook (all closed) for people looking to recycle, exchange or sell their used goods. Make sure you read the rules for each before joining and posting your stuff.
>
> - [Mottainai Japan](https://www.facebook.com/groups/276522392525201/)
> - [Tokyo Garage Sale – Pick Up Only](https://www.facebook.com/groups/tokyogaragesalepickuponly)
> - [Japan Garage Sale: Everything Else](https://www.facebook.com/groups/JapanGarageSaleEverythingElse/)
> - [In Search Of- Japan](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1375330762784969)
>
> **Tokyo Freecycle**
>
> Freecycling is a system popular around the world which encourages people to gift usable items to anyone who wants them. In Tokyo this happens through a [Yahoo! Groups mailing list](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/tokyofreecycle/info).  Members send emails to the list either offering items or asking for items. Everything offered must be completely free—although if you want something, you’ll probably have to pay for the shipping.

[In context, note that the person who wants the item pays for shipping.]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the products in India!

1) Go to http://www.amazon.in

2) search "step down transformer 220v to 110v"

Otherwise
https://geo.craigslist.org/iso/jp

Comment: Step down transformer powerful enough for wok, kettle and blenders will cost more than buying all them new.

Comment: It depends on kitchen stuff price

Comment: 1000W is US$60.  Some Japanese still throw unneeded brand new items away in the trash.

Comment: why? when it would work just fine in Japan...